# How can I use async task

Tags: android, view, android-asynctask

How can I put this to Async task in android. The view is taking most of the main thread so I am trying to put it in new thread.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_layout, null);
    holder.txt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    holder.flag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

    holder.txt.setText(result[position]);
    holder.flag.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class).putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, result[position]);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

The another class is like this . I Cant understand what is using the most part of the main thread

```
public static class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

    public DetailFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) {
            String forecastStr = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_text)).setText(forecastStr);
        }

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry I cant get you.

Comment: *"The view is taking most of the main thread"* - what makes you say that? Do you have any data to back up that claim? At a quick glance, I don't see anything major wrong with the code you've given (although you should look into correctly applying the ViewHolder pattern and inflating layouts), nor anything that looks like a very heavy operation.

Comment: This is the logcat`1-06 02:06:14.625 17955-17955/com.example.vikky.basic_3 W/Resources: Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0c006e}
11-06 02:06:15.927 17955-17955/com.example.vikky.basic_3 I/Choreographer: Skipped 77 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-06 02:06:17.146 17955-17955/com.example.vikky.basic_3 I/Choreographer: Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-06 02:06:20.521 17955-17955/com.example.vikky.basic_3 W/Resources: Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0c006d}`

Comment: This is being shown in the logcat. The application is running very slow.

Comment: *"The application may be doing too much work on its main thread"* is not the equivalent of *"The view is taking most of the main thread"*. It's a hint that *something* is taking up more time on the ui thread than it should. Most likely, it's not view-related at all, but rather has to do with other code you've written (i.e. database operations, file i/o etc). I suggest you enable [StrictMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) and/or use [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/traceview.html) to further pinpoint the origin of the slowdown.

Comment: Thanks for your support I am looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong because the most of the operations with the UI should be on the main thread (and updating the UI should be always on the main thread).

Probably there is another code which is taking most of the main thread (URL requests, loading files from disk, data parsing, etc.).

But here is an example of AsyncTask usage:

```
AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         //code here
     }
});
```

Comment: This is the another class used in the App.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the [ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) pattern correctly.

The idea of the ViewHolder pattern is to limit the number of layout inflation and costly operations like `findViewById()`. Your implementation completely ignore the `convertView` and inflate a new layout every time!

If your layout is complex, this might cause a visible hit in performance.

A better implementation would be:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView != null) {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    else {
        holder = new ViewHolder();  
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_layout, parent, false);
        holder.txt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        holder.flag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    holder.txt.setText(result[position]);
    holder.flag.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class).putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, result[position]);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

You should also consider using the [`ListView.setOnItemClickListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29) instead of creating an new `OnClickListener` for each item of the list.

Comment: After changing the code its showing eror. `E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 15:09:47.272 12934-12934/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.vikky.basic_3, PID: 12934
11-06 15:09:47.272 12934-12934/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.widget.TextView com.example.vikky.basic_3.CustomAdapter$ViewHolder.txt' on a null object reference
11-06 15:09:47.272 1294-12934/com.example.vikky.basic_3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.vikky.basic_3.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:97)`

Comment: Ah! I forgot to link the holder to the view! This is corrected